# Is it possible to increase the size of the mouse pointer?

Tags: mouse-pointer

I'm running Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 on a 3440x1440 resolution, combine that with bad eyesight and the default mouse pointer size can be hard to see.

Is there a way to increase it's size?

Comment: The answer below is the best one. You don't need to install ubuntu-tweaks or use vi/gedit.

Answer (score 23):

Alternatively, you can also try a GUI method.
Open *Settings* → *Universal Access* → *Cursor Size*:

[image: Universall Access window]

and choose your preferred size.

[image: Cursor size window]

Comment: Deleted my response ... gnome-control-center is there (launched from cmd line it works for mate).

Comment: thank you very much! This is very easy, that's the way it should be!

Comment: Similar [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1158191/how-to-change-mouse-pointer-size-and-appearance-in-gnome-18-04) from askubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. If only the developers of these GUIs would make life as easy as this answer ;)

Answer (score 11):

**More flexible, granular and precise than** the options available via **Settings > Universal Access > Cursor Size**

View the existing cursor-size (default 24):

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-size
```

Set a different size:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-size 32
```

Then logout/login

Answer (score 2):

Budgie has a control-center, which is quite new since 2017.

Here is shown how to go on with control-center in budgie:

http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2017/08/intro-to-budgie-desktop-104.html

In window-manager of gnome, there is a control-center too (its name is gnome-control-center) and in gnome
you can adjust mouse and mouse-pointer. In gnome-control-center there is an entry for "accessibility" special for handicapped people. For people who see bad, there can be increased the desktop with its bigger icons.