# Increase mouse cursor size on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: cursor

In the past `dconf-editor` could be used to change the cursor size.

I installed Ubuntu 20.04. I changed the value to `64` rebooted, and still the size of the cursor is unchanged.

How to increase the cursor size on Ubuntu 20.04?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Go to the Settings panel... choose **Universal Access**, then **Cursor Size**...

[image]

Comment: Great! This is much easier than dconf-editor. Thank you!

Comment: @guettli Glad it worked for you. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I have a weird behavior: basically the mouse has increased on apps, like firefox, but it shows still the original (small) size, when I focus back on  desktop...any idea?

Comment: @jjrr What version Ubuntu? Running Wayland? GNOME?

Comment: sorry: I am also on U 20.04. The issue holds on both Cinnamon 4.4.8 and GNOME 3.36. I have increased the related values in `dconf` for all the related sections, such as `/org/cinnamon/desktop/interface/cursor-size` or `/org/gnome/desktop/interface/cursor-size`

Comment: ok, I upgraded to U 20.10 and it seems to be working - I think the issue is related with the graphical card, as `libnvidia-compute-440` was preventing `do-release-upgrade` (I fixed it downgrading it). During the upgrade the nvidia server crashed (fortunately, it did not prevent the upgrade)

Comment: @jjrr You may have to select the nouveau video driver, and then `sudo apt-get purge *nvidia*` to remove all Nvidia software, and reinstall the proper version for your model Nvidia card and 20.xx.

Comment: yeah, thanks @heynnema -- I have just installed `nvidia-driver-455` ... for now it seems all fine

Comment: What can I do if the cursor theme does not have other sizes in it? My cursor theme only has one really small size.

Comment: @AaronFranke What version Ubuntu? Have you tried all of the answers shown here?

Comment: I'm on 22.04 in Hyper-V. Most of the time it is large but I can't see the whole arrow: lower part is missing. Before PyCharm it is small.
UPDATE: Now I restarted PyCharm. I have large arrow there too. :-)

Answer (score 7):

`dconf-editor` still works for me in Ubuntu 20.04.01...

[image: dconf-editor set mouse cursor to 60]

Are you sure you clicked "Apply" (or changed the view) before exiting?

[image: dconf-editor "Apply" bar]

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Setting-->Accessibility-->Cursor Size
Now you can choose from small to the largest.