# Cannot see cursor on new Ubuntu install

Tags: cursor

New to Linux.

Installed Ubuntu ... version ???

Cannot see cursor. Googled for suggestions. Tried several command line instructions to increase cursor size but none worked.

I am sight challenged and without a large cursor Ubuntu is inaccessible.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Increase mouse cursor size on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1266951/increase-mouse-cursor-size-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing which version of Ubuntu you're using, these instructions may not be 100% accurate. However, if you are using Ubuntu 21.04, this is how you can change the size of your mouse cursor using only the keyboard:

1. Open the Settings application by pressing <kbd>Super</kbd> (this may be a Windows key on your keyboard) and type "Settings" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
   [image: Settings Options]
   If you see several options, as in the screenshot above, the left-most icon will be opened. If "Settings" is not left-most, you can use the arrow keys to navigate. Choose the round icon. You should see an application that looks like this:
   [image: Settings]
2. Locate the "Accessibility Options". This is most easily done by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (for "Find"), then typing "Access":
   [image: Find Access]
   Press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to confirm the selection.
3. Press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> button three times. You may see "High Contrast" has a highlight around it.
4. Press the Down Arrow twice. This will highlight the "Cursor Size" option. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to bring up the options:
   [image: Arrow Sizes]
5. Use the arrow keys to select the size you are most comfortable with, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
6. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to close the modal window.
7. Move the mouse and maybe use a scroll button. This should trigger a proper refresh and you will hopefully see that the pointer is now the size you set it as.

There are a number of accessibility features available that may help you navigate and use the system in comfort. Welcome to Ubuntu!

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Your instructions did not work for me but somehow I got to the screen you show in #4 and change the cursor size successfully.