# Increase mouse cursor size on Ubuntu Budgie 22.04

Tags: unity, mouse, cursor, dconf

I tried all the suggestions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1266951/increase-mouse-cursor-size-on-ubuntu-20-04) but none seem to work for me (after reboot/logout). Interesting that the "Budgie Desktop Settings" are 'honored' (change Style/Cursors/DMZ-Black|White) but Cursor Size don't seem to save. Other changes in both dconf-editor and Universal Access are visible, mostly immediately. This was a fresh install of 22.04, after having issues upgrading 21.10 to 22.04. Intel Video, not NVidia, no 3d Party/Secure Boot stuff.

[[image: 2]]
[[image: 3]]

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be with Firefox, not the Budgie Desktop. Firefox takes control of all cursors. Finding this out was quite the saga, and Budgie isn't quite the same as a Gnome experience. I think I'll give up on Budgie, and stay with MATE or mainstream Ubuntu for the 22.04 LTS cycle.