# How to change mouse pointer in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, customization, mouse-pointer

Is there any way to change the mouse pointer (color, size, etc)?
I believe there used to be options with compiz, but with the latest versions of Ubuntu even there I haven't seen many mouse options to customize.

I'm working on a 32" 4K screen, most windows in dark mode and the pointer is black with only a very fine white line around it. The majority of time I use my keyboard so I don't keep track of where my mouse is.
But when I do need it, even moving the mouse around, it takes quite a bit of effort to keep track of the pointer so I'd prefer to change both size and color so it's easier to spot.

Comment: The mouse pointer color can be changed from GNOME Tweaks (check if you have it installed) and size from Settings->Accessibility/Universal Access->Cursor size.

Comment: Does these answer your question? [How to change mouse cursor and theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66843/how-to-change-mouse-cursor-and-theme) (command line answers might be an overkill), [Is it possible to increase the size of the mouse pointer?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1040807/816190) and/or [How do I change the cursor and its size?](https://askubuntu.com/q/126491/816190)

Comment: @Kulfy The gnome tweak tool is useful. The referenced question does have links to YT videos that have since been deleted, but at least it puts me in the right direction. The installed themes are not what I was looking for but I think I can find some better ones on my own. Thanks.

Comment: I'll just remove links to YT videos to avoid confusions. Thanks for mentioning that. Also, by default, you must at least have options for DMZ-White and White Glass cursors.

Comment: I do, but they're no better than the Yaru that was set.